# ¿Cómo hago para obtener el número de elementos positivos de una matriz?

Tags: c++, c

He intentado sacar el código para este problema, la verdad no se nada de c/c++ , así que me basé en otros códigos, entre ellos uno de como hacer tablas y otro de como contar los números positivos y negativos, sin embargo no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal y tampoco sé como corregirlo.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numeros[100][100],filas=0,columnas=0;
    int auxiliar=0;
    int positivo,negativo;
    positivo=0;
    negativo=0;
    
    cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: "; cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de columnas: "; cin>>columnas;
    
    //Rellenando la matriz  
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>auxiliar;
            if (auxiliar < 0) 
            {
                positivo+=+1;
            }
            else
                negativo+=+1;
                numeros[i][j] = auxiliar;
        }
    } 
    cout<<"\nMostrando matriz\n\n";
    
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++)
        {
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nLa cantidad de positivos son:"<<positivo<<end1;
    cout<<"\nLa cantidad de negativos son:"<<negativo<<end1;
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu código está bien... cual sería el error?...

Comment: Reemplaza `end1` por `endl`, con esto ya compilaría tu código, lo demás está bien...

Comment: Me parece que los if están invertidos. if (auxiliar < 0)  aumentas los positivos, no debería aumentar los negativos??

Comment: estas contando numeros negativos en la variable de positivo, invierte la condicion, y luego cambia los end1 por endl;

Comment: En realidad conviene escribir "\n" o '\n' ya que `endl` es más lento porque llama a la función `flush`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo esta mal escrito en la parte de los `end1`, lo correcto es `endl`, otro error que se ve es en la condición, esta invertida.
codigo corregido:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numeros[100][100],filas=0,columnas=0;
    int auxiliar=0;
    int positivo,negativo;
    positivo=0;
    negativo=0;
    
    cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: "; cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de columnas: "; cin>>columnas;
    
    //Rellenando la matriz  
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>auxiliar;
            if (auxiliar > 0) positivo+=1;
            else negativo+=1;
            numeros[i][j] = auxiliar;
        }
    } 
    cout<<"\nMostrando matriz\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nLa cantidad de positivos son:"<<positivo<<endl;
    cout<<"\nLa cantidad de negativos son:"<<negativo<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```